# Как обновить state при первом клике?

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

```
 onSelectCard = () => {
        this.setState((state) => {
            return {
                firstGuess: 'some words'
            };
        });
        console.log('firstGuess: ', this.state.firstGuess)
}
```

`this.state.firstGuess` обновляется лишь при втором клике, а **нужно при первом**

то есть при первом клике `console.log('firstGuess: ', this.state.firstGuess)` - выводит старое значение `this.state.firstGuess`

при втором клике уже обновляется и `console.log` выводит *firstGuess:  some words*

Почему state обновляет только при втором клике, как можно это исправить?

```
onSelectCard = () => {
            this.setState({ firstGuess: 'some words'});
            console.log('firstGuess: ', this.state.firstGuess)
}
```

этот код работает так же.

Пожалуйста, подскажите как быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` работает асинхронно

> Вызовы setState являются асинхронными, поэтому не стоит рассчитывать, что this.state отобразит новое значение мгновенно после вызова setState.

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value